# Determine if a Java class is a portable SE class

Tags: java

I'm working on a Java code analyzer (AST stuff using the Trees API) and I'm trying to create a report on whether or not the code being inspected makes use of non-portable APIs. Stuff like the sun packages and such should cause a warning. Where is the defined list of SE 7 portable classes? Is there anything more machine parsable than the SE Javadocs? If the Javadocs are "the" portable listing how are they generated from all the java source from OpenJDK? Is portable code kept separate or ...?

Comment: Javac generates a warning when using non portable api I think. You could maybe investigate there.

Comment: Till Java 9 with a module system, list the classes of oracle's Java, list the classes of OpenJDK. The intersection "should" be portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core SE classes are defined by one of the files used in the JDK build process which can be found at: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/make/docs/CORE_PKGS.gmk

```
# CORE_PKGS is the list of packages that form the
# Java API Specification.
#
### ***IMPORTANT NOTE***
### There is also a "REGEXP" variable in the docs/makefile that
### determines which table the packages go in on the main page.
### Currently, there is only table ("Platform Packages") and
### everything goes in it, so REGEXP is "*". But if that policy
### changes, packages added will need to be reflected in  that
### list of wildcard expressions, as well.
###
CORE_PKGS =                                      \
  java.applet                                    \
  java.awt                                       \
  java.awt.color                                 \
  java.awt.datatransfer                          \
  java.awt.dnd                                   \
  java.awt.event                                 \
  java.awt.font                                  \
  java.awt.geom                                  \
  java.awt.im                                    \
  java.awt.im.spi                                \
  java.awt.image                                 \
  java.awt.image.renderable                      \
  java.awt.print                                 \
  java.beans                                     \
  java.beans.beancontext                         \
  java.io                                        \
  java.lang                                      \
  java.lang.annotation                           \
  java.lang.instrument                           \
  java.lang.invoke                               \
  java.lang.management                           \
  java.lang.ref                                  \
  java.lang.reflect                              \
  java.math                                      \
  java.net                                       \
  java.nio                                       \
  java.nio.channels                              \
  java.nio.channels.spi                          \
  java.nio.charset                               \
  java.nio.charset.spi                           \
  java.nio.file                  \
  java.nio.file.attribute            \
  java.nio.file.spi              \
  java.rmi                                       \
  java.rmi.activation                            \
  java.rmi.dgc                                   \
  java.rmi.registry                              \
  java.rmi.server                                \
  java.security                                  \
  java.security.acl                              \
  java.security.cert                             \
  java.security.interfaces                       \
  java.security.spec                             \
  java.sql                                       \
  java.text                                      \
  java.text.spi                                  \
  java.util                                      \
  java.util.concurrent                           \
  java.util.concurrent.atomic                    \
  java.util.concurrent.locks                     \
  java.util.jar                                  \
  java.util.logging                              \
  java.util.prefs                                \
  java.util.regex                                \
  java.util.spi                                  \
  java.util.zip                                  \
  javax.accessibility                            \
  javax.activation                               \
  javax.activity                                 \
  javax.annotation                               \
  javax.annotation.processing                    \
  javax.crypto                                   \
  javax.crypto.interfaces                        \
  javax.crypto.spec                              \
  javax.imageio                                  \
  javax.imageio.event                            \
  javax.imageio.metadata                         \
  javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg                     \
  javax.imageio.plugins.bmp                      \
  javax.imageio.spi                              \
  javax.imageio.stream                           \
  javax.jws                                      \
  javax.jws.soap                                 \
  javax.lang.model                               \
  javax.lang.model.element                       \
  javax.lang.model.type                          \
  javax.lang.model.util                          \
  javax.management                               \
  javax.management.loading                       \
  javax.management.monitor                       \
  javax.management.relation                      \
  javax.management.openmbean                     \
  javax.management.timer                         \
  javax.management.modelmbean                    \
  javax.management.remote                        \
  javax.management.remote.rmi                    \
  javax.naming                                   \
  javax.naming.directory                         \
  javax.naming.event                             \
  javax.naming.ldap                              \
  javax.naming.spi                               \
  javax.net                                      \
  javax.net.ssl                                  \
  javax.print                                    \
  javax.print.attribute                          \
  javax.print.attribute.standard                 \
  javax.print.event                              \
  javax.rmi                                      \
  javax.rmi.CORBA                                \
  javax.rmi.ssl                                  \
  javax.script                                   \
  javax.security.auth                            \
  javax.security.auth.callback                   \
  javax.security.auth.kerberos                   \
  javax.security.auth.login                      \
  javax.security.auth.spi                        \
  javax.security.auth.x500                       \
  javax.security.cert                            \
  javax.security.sasl                            \
  javax.sound.sampled                            \
  javax.sound.sampled.spi                        \
  javax.sound.midi                               \
  javax.sound.midi.spi                           \
  javax.sql                                      \
  javax.sql.rowset                               \
  javax.sql.rowset.serial                        \
  javax.sql.rowset.spi                           \
  javax.swing                                    \
  javax.swing.border                             \
  javax.swing.colorchooser                       \
  javax.swing.filechooser                        \
  javax.swing.event                              \
  javax.swing.table                              \
  javax.swing.text                               \
  javax.swing.text.html                          \
  javax.swing.text.html.parser                   \
  javax.swing.text.rtf                           \
  javax.swing.tree                               \
  javax.swing.undo                               \
  javax.swing.plaf                               \
  javax.swing.plaf.basic                         \
  javax.swing.plaf.metal                         \
  javax.swing.plaf.multi                         \
  javax.swing.plaf.nimbus                        \
  javax.swing.plaf.synth                         \
  javax.tools                                    \
  javax.transaction                              \
  javax.transaction.xa                           \
  javax.xml.parsers                              \
  javax.xml.bind                                 \
  javax.xml.bind.annotation                      \
  javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters             \
  javax.xml.bind.attachment                      \
  javax.xml.bind.helpers                         \
  javax.xml.bind.util                            \
  javax.xml.soap                                 \
  javax.xml.ws                                   \
  javax.xml.ws.handler                           \
  javax.xml.ws.handler.soap                      \
  javax.xml.ws.http                              \
  javax.xml.ws.soap                              \
  javax.xml.ws.spi                               \
  javax.xml.ws.spi.http                          \
  javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing                      \
  javax.xml.transform                            \
  javax.xml.transform.sax                        \
  javax.xml.transform.dom                        \
  javax.xml.transform.stax                       \
  javax.xml.transform.stream                     \
  javax.xml                                      \
  javax.xml.crypto               \
  javax.xml.crypto.dom               \
  javax.xml.crypto.dsig              \
  javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom          \
  javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo          \
  javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec             \
  javax.xml.datatype                             \
  javax.xml.validation                           \
  javax.xml.namespace                            \
  javax.xml.xpath                                \
  javax.xml.stream                               \
  javax.xml.stream.events                        \
  javax.xml.stream.util                          \
  org.ietf.jgss                                  \
  org.omg.CORBA                                  \
  org.omg.CORBA.DynAnyPackage                    \
  org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage                       \
  org.omg.CORBA.TypeCodePackage                  \
  org.omg.stub.java.rmi                          \
  org.omg.CORBA.portable                         \
  org.omg.CORBA_2_3                              \
  org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable                     \
  org.omg.CosNaming                              \
  org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtPackage      \
  org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage         \
  org.omg.SendingContext                         \
  org.omg.PortableServer                         \
  org.omg.PortableServer.CurrentPackage          \
  org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage              \
  org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage       \
  org.omg.PortableServer.ServantLocatorPackage   \
  org.omg.PortableServer.portable                \
  org.omg.PortableInterceptor                    \
  org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage \
  org.omg.Messaging                              \
  org.omg.IOP                                    \
  org.omg.IOP.CodecFactoryPackage                \
  org.omg.IOP.CodecPackage                       \
  org.omg.Dynamic                                \
  org.omg.DynamicAny                             \
  org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyPackage               \
  org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyFactoryPackage        \
  org.w3c.dom                                    \
  org.w3c.dom.events                             \
  org.w3c.dom.bootstrap                          \
  org.w3c.dom.ls                                 \
  org.xml.sax                                    \
  org.xml.sax.ext                                \
  org.xml.sax.helpers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you analize .class files you can use Javassist http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/ to get a list of all class names referenced from a class. Then you can analize class packages. Classes which comprise Java public API are in subpackages of java, javax and org.omg, org.w3c.dom, org.xml.sax packages

Comment: Getting the list of used classes isn't where I'm stuck. It is knowing for sure if a given package/class/method is portable across implementations. I'm not 100% sure that all the java/javax classes in rt.jar are defined in the public API and I'd like to know. Also some of the EE classes start with the same names and I'd like to report that code uses 100% portable *SE* classes.

Comment: OK. If clazz.getClassLoader() == null it is from rt.jar